# Haskell Tree - searching through tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm having issues with my assignment: I'm trying to write a code that makes a list of all node-values I tell him to (for example, all nodes with the value 4 into a neat list).

I wrote the following:

```hs
findValue :: a -> (MyTree a) -> [a]
findValue x Leaf = []
findValue x (Node a l r)
    |a == x = x++(findValue x l)++(findValue x r)
    |a /= x = (findValue x l)++(findValue x r)
```

I had defined trees as follow:

```hs
data MyTree a = Leaf  | Node a (MyTree a) (MyTree a)
```

I get the following error-message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for findValue :: a -> MyTree a -> [a]
          at assignment.hs:10:14
    Relevant bindings include
      r :: MyTree a (bound at assignment.hs:12:25)
      l :: MyTree a (bound at assignment.hs:12:23)
      a :: a (bound at assignment.hs:12:21)
      x :: a (bound at assignment.hs:12:11)
      findValue :: a -> MyTree a -> [a]
        (bound at assignment.hs:11:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: x ++ (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)
```

I would be very happy if someone explained the error message to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `(++)` is `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`, but the type of `x` is `a`. Thus you can write

`x : (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)`
(which uses the "cons" operator `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`), or

```
[x] ++ (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)
```

Here's how you should determine this yourself:

The error says `Couldn't match exptected type '[a]' with actual type 'a' ...
in the first argument of '(++)', namely 'x'`

This means that the argument `x` to `(++)` (on the line indicated) *should* have type `[a]` (that's the *expected* type), but actually has type `a` (the *inferred* type).

Then you should look up the type signature for `(++)` to see what the problem might be (e.g. using [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/), or [ghci](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html#idp7292880)) In your case, the problem was that the types of the first and second arguments to `(++)` were not the same, but they should be.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you are doing. `findValue` is of the type `a -> MyTree a -> [a]` which means that `x` is of the type `a`.

However, the `(++)` operator is of the type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`, but you are writing `x ++ (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)`. Hence it gives you an error saying:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for findValue :: a -> MyTree a -> [a]
          at assignment.hs:10:14
    Relevant bindings include
      r :: MyTree a (bound at assignment.hs:12:25)
      l :: MyTree a (bound at assignment.hs:12:23)
      a :: a (bound at assignment.hs:12:21)
      x :: a (bound at assignment.hs:12:11)
      findValue :: a -> MyTree a -> [a]
        (bound at assignment.hs:11:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: x ++ (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)
```

The error message clearly says that it `Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’`. It further tells you where the problem is, `In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’`. It even tells you where to find that expression, `In the expression: x ++ (findValue x l) ++ (findValue x r)`.

Haskell error messages might look very scary, but they are actually quite informative and easy to understand. Don't let phrases like `‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by` scare you.

I understand that it's easy to give up when the second sentence you read is something you don't understand, and I understand that it's easier to post a question about it on SO. Do yourself a favor and don't. Learn how to understand error messages.

Give a man a fish and he'll eat for one day. Teach a man to fish and he'll eat for his entire life.

---

BTW, why do you need a `findValue` function of the type `a -> MyTree a -> [a]`? It would make more sense to have:

```
hasValue :: a -> MyTree a -> Bool
hasValue x Leaf         = False
hasValue x (Node a l r)
    | a == x            = True
    | otherwise         = findValue x l || findValue x r

numValue :: a -> MyTree a -> Int
numValue x Leaf         = 0
numValue x (Node a l r)
    | a == x            = depth + 1
    | otherwise         = depth
    where depth = findValue x l + findValue x r
```

To me it doesn't make any sense to have a `findValue` function because given `findValue x t` the result is:

1. Either an empty list or a non-empty list (`False` or `True` respectively). Hence `hasValue`.
2. A list of only `x` values repeated, in which case only the length matters. Hence `numValue`.

   ```
   findValue :: a -> MyTree a -> [a]
   findValue x t = replicate (numValue x t) x
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
When I read "Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’", I thought "Okay, somewhere is an element where there should be a list", I looked at my code, didn't find the error where he told me to "In the first argument f '(++)', namely 'x'", because I thought "But I said x==a, why is suddenly x wrong, It's getting concatenated into a list, so it is a list at the end, and not a bare element. Maybe I mixed it up elsewhere and now Haskell can't read my line. Maybe it's syntax. Oh man, I should ask, I have no clue."